# How can I create a GIF out of a sequence of PNG files without the previous image appearing on the next frame?

Tags: command-line, image-processing, png, gif

I'll let the `.gif` I have do most of the talk: [The GIF](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Iaid.jpg)

A bit of backstory: I have 100 PNG files (which can be seen [here on imgur](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sdjsv.jpg)), each one is a frame of an animation. With those files, I have to make a `.gif`.

I used:

```
convert -delay 5 -loop 0 Frame_7_00000*.png" animated.gif
```

To make the gif linked above.

Basically, as the question says, the previous image loaded stays on the next frame, and so on until the gif is over. I want to know if it's possible to make a gif where this does not happen. If possible, a command line answer is preferred.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I assume you're using http://www.imagemagick.org/. The `-dispose` command describes what is to be done with the frame after its delay (when the next frame is loaded). Info here: http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/anim_basics/#dispose

```
-dispose previous
```

try:

```
convert -delay 5 -dispose previous -loop 0 Frame_7_00000*.png" animated.gif
```